# Vulnerabilities shown in Security Command Center(SCC) Dashboard in Google Cloud

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

**Vulnerabilities shown in Security Command Center Dashboard**

Security Command Center Dashboard in Google Cloud shows a bunch of vulnerabilities, we have fixed so few issues and its not clear how to initiate another assessment of vulnerabilities seen across all assets. How can we trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of vulnerabilities shown in the Security Command Center:

- **Security Health Analytics**: this one (currently in beta) runs automatically twice a day, 12-hours apart. As of now it can't be run manually.
- **Web Security Scanner**: this one essentially display results of the Web Security Scan that you can set up and run yourself as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/scanning).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to relaunch a scan to view if your action are now "green". However, keep in mind that your target is not to have 0 vulnerabilities reported by SCC, but to have 0 issue that enforces YOUR security policy.

For example, a firewall rule open in 0.0.0.0/0 will appear as a vulnerabilities. It could be, or not. If you have a Loadbalancer, created manually or by GKE, this firewall rules is created automatically. Is it a vulnerability?

- Yes if you don't want any external access.
- No if it's your website and you want to allow all people across the world to browse it.

Same case for bucket with public access. Public for serving static content like images or videos? or Public with restricted data that nobody outside the company should see?

SCC is simply a tool, act wisely!